# How to handle this exception related to Excel

Tags: excel

In our application,user can export some data to an excel file.When he clicks export, we pop-up windows file dialog where he chooses an existing excel file to overwrite,or give a new name.But,when he overwrites an existing file,he is asked by windows "does he want to replace",and if he clicks no,an exception is raised

```
Exception from HResult: at Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.Saveas
```

How can we detect this exception? Or,is it possible to detect "no" and handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to handle the Excel error following tips on this page : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

First, set an :

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
```

Don't forget to put an :

```
Exit Sub
```

And then put :

```
ErrHandle:
'Use Err.Number (need to check which one it is though)
If Err.Number == 1 then
'Do what you want
End Sub
```

You just have to find which err number it is (e.g. by debugging) and treat this exception,

Hope that helps,

Regards,

Max